# LazyInitializationException Within a @Transactional Method

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactional

I am running into the `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` error when I try to access a lazy loaded exception when excecuting the following:

```
@Transactional
public void displayAddresses()
{
     Person person = getPersonByID(1234);
     List<Address> addresses = person.getAddresses(); // Exception Thrown Here

     for(Address address : addresses)
          System.out.println(address.getFullAddress());
}
```

My entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table("PERSON_TBL")
public class Person
{
     ...

     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Address.class, mappedBy="person")
     private List<Address> addresses;

     ...
}

@Entity
@Table("ADDRESS_TBL")
public class Address
{
     ...

     @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person.class)
     @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName="PERSON_ID")
     Person person;

     ...
}
```

I was under the impression that by using the @Transactional annotation in my `displayAddresses()` method, it would keep the session alive until the method was completed, allowing me to access the lazy-loaded Address collection.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

In accordance with Tomasz's advice: Within my `displayAddresses()` method, the status of `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(),` turned out to be `false`.

That does narrow down the problem, but why would my Transaction not be active at this point?

Comment: Can you call `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`? It should return `true`. Otherwise `@Transasctional` is not working.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I edited my original post to include more information based on your suggestion.

Comment: Do you have `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your configuration? Is your `displayAddresses()` method in a Spring-managed bean? Do you call this method from outside or from other transactional method?

Comment: How do you invoke the displayAddresses() method - from a method of the same bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `<tx:annotation-driven />` in my configuration file and using a Spring-managed version of my service class (to call the displayAddresses() method) did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

This is already answered, but just wanted to post an alternative answer which worked for me in a similar case - for future generations ;)

In my case the issue was caused by the fact that the instance which contained the lazy-loaded collection had been manually evicted (all within transaction boundaries).

Comment: It wasn't like that in my case, but it got me thinking - and it turned out that at one point an  entity was cached (using ehcache) instead of dto - make sure that you are not doing it either