# LazyInitializationException with active transaction and connection open

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0

I know this has been asked many times (already cheched most of the post here and in other sites), but I dont get to solve my problem.

My setup is: jpa 2 + hibernate 4 + spring 4 + primefaces + jboss eap 7

The problem: I got a lazy collection into another bean, but when I get to call the .size() method on the  bean, it throws the "LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pe.controlLines.data.model.Activity.activityRisks, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Im sure i got an active transaction following this [LazyInitializationException Within a @Transactional Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318127/lazyinitializationexception-within-a-transactional-method) and  http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/ so I'm 100% sure theres a transaction running at the time.

My entity clases:

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long companyId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Activity companieActivities;

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<SourceSupervision> sourceSupervisions;
```

and the nested class

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long activityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parentActivityId")
    private Activity parent;

    @Column
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")
    private String name;

    @Column
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @Analyzer(definition = "searchtokenanalyzer")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Collection<ActivityRisk> activityRisks = new ArrayList<ActivityRisk>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Collection<Word> words;

    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Rol> rolesForActivity;
```

the bussines delegate is anotated like this (the bussines is called from the page controller):

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
@Transactional
public class SystemConfigurationBussinesDelegate {
```

Got an inicialization of the reference to the entity, which executes fine. (this is from the aboce class)

```
private Company currentCompany;

    private Risk currentRisk;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        //((WordDAO)wordDAO).startIndexer();
        currentCompany = genericDAO.get(Company.class, 1l);
    }
```

But in this method

```
public List<Danger> getDangers(){

        List<Danger> returnValue = new ArrayList<Danger>();
        System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        Hibernate.initialize(currentCompany.getCompanieActivities());
        currentCompany.getCompanieActivities().getActivityRisks().size();
        for( ActivityRisk aRisk : currentCompany.getCompanieActivities().getActivityRisks() ){
            Risk risk = aRisk.getRisk();
            if(risk == currentRisk){
                returnValue = new ArrayList<Danger>(aRisk.getDangers());
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

the sysout returns true so the transaction is active, and I can see an open connection to the database, the Hibernate.inicialize works fine, and the call to currentCompany.getCompanieActivities().getActivityRisks().size(); throws the exception.

Could it be some problem with contexts or somethng similar?

My spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pe.controlLines" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="java:/ControllinesDS"/>
    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> -->
    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
       <!-- <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>net.javabeat.spring.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>co.com.testTalos.model.Storage</value>
                <value>co.com.testTalos.model.Buyer</value>
                <value>co.com.testTalos.model.Preferences</value>
            </list>
        </property>-->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.pe.controlLines.data.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">C:/DEVELOPMENT/lucene/indexes</prop>


            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is to do with calling the transactional method inside `@PostConstruct`. By design spring tx aspects are/may not active on postconstruct method because not all beans guaranteed to have finished constructing. Try searching this topic, I remember encountering this by surprise too but there are plenty helpful articles.

Since then my prefered alternatives when I need tx on postconstruct is to <strike>use programmatic transaction (see Spring TransactionTemplate patterns)</strike> use the ContextRefreshedEvent. See below example:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // This method will be executed at context startup or refresh
    // It is guaranteed all beans have finish constructing, hence
    // AOP tx is available
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: U can't even imagine how happy you just made me...thank you, with your answer and some JUnit test I got to solve all of my issues.